# ubuntu 20.04 Intel ax200 Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

Tags: linux, wifi, intel

i have an issue on a Fujitsu Board D3713-R2 with a AMD Ryzen Processor. The ax200 Module is populate on a adapter Board form m.2 to pcie.

The module is recognized on the pci.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
               LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
```

The dmesg message shows a ADVANCED_SYSASSERT

```
[ 2481.077892] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[ 2481.077924] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[ 2481.077933] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 2481.077936] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[ 2481.078629] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-56.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 2481.078682] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[ 2481.099202] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 2482.124779] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x4, CPU2 Status: 0x1
[ 2482.124802] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: UMAC PC: 0xc00c0eb2
[ 2482.124818] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[ 2482.124825] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[ 2482.153867] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 2482.153876] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: -63936083
[ 2482.153881] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-56.ucode
[ 2482.153887] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xCB78D5F6 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT           
[ 2482.153891] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x247BA027 | trm_hw_status0
[ 2482.153895] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5434B58F | trm_hw_status1
[ 2482.153899] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xEF42C364 | branchlink2
[ 2482.153902] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD1D55FF2 | interruptlink1
[ 2482.153906] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA8D9B6EB | interruptlink2
[ 2482.153909] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x118596CF | data1
[ 2482.153913] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA4DBF05B | data2
[ 2482.153916] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x015A11FE | data3
[ 2482.153920] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5B197436 | beacon time
[ 2482.153923] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x46BAF115 | tsf low
[ 2482.153926] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x34BE2702 | tsf hi
[ 2482.153930] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x8964617A | time gp1
[ 2482.153933] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xE056FF48 | time gp2
[ 2482.153936] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xC5451E56 | uCode revision type
[ 2482.153940] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD987B2A4 | uCode version major
[ 2482.153943] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x81BC3C6E | uCode version minor
[ 2482.153946] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xCBA8B9D3 | hw version
[ 2482.153950] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xB61EDDB6 | board version
[ 2482.153953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4D9749DB | hcmd
[ 2482.153956] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xE2CC9BDA | isr0
[ 2482.153959] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5EACEAB7 | isr1
[ 2482.153963] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x48F599E6 | isr2
[ 2482.153966] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x97B6071F | isr3
[ 2482.153969] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xE690E236 | isr4
[ 2482.153972] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x1797CE16 | last cmd Id
[ 2482.153976] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x690C9A6E | wait_event
[ 2482.153979] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x1710BE22 | l2p_control
[ 2482.153982] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x10A6216C | l2p_duration
[ 2482.153985] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9483C224 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 2482.153989] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x42EAAF63 | l2p_addr_match
[ 2482.153992] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9118B7D7 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 2482.153995] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x8931764D | timestamp
[ 2482.153998] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x6F4E493D | flow_handler
[ 2482.154116] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 2482.154120] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[ 2482.154124] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[ 2482.154128] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 2482.154131] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2
[ 2482.154134] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[ 2482.154138] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x804836C4 | umac interruptlink2
[ 2482.154141] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[ 2482.154144] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x804836C4 | umac data2
[ 2482.154147] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 2482.154151] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major
[ 2482.154154] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[ 2482.154157] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000FDF8D | frame pointer
[ 2482.154160] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xC0887F40 | stack pointer
[ 2482.154164] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 2482.154167] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 2482.154255] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[ 2482.154301] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 2482.154347] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 2482.154392] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 2482.154439] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 2482.154484] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 2482.154530] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 2482.154576] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 2482.154622] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 2482.154668] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 2482.154716] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 2482.154765] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 2482.154812] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 2482.154860] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 2482.705479] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

kernel version is the 5.8.0-45-generic

Bluetooth is working

```
hcitool dev
Devices:
       hci0    F8:5E:A0:49:0C:04
```

many thanks for your support

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You say you have an issue. It would help if you said precisely what issue you have. For example, if this is a combined Wifi and Bluetooth device, you could say that the Wifi function is not recognized and you think this has something to do with the failed INIT, and what can be done so that Wifi is recognized.